# Giving different names to df using a for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, global

I have a df in python with different cities.

[image]

I am trying to create a df for each city.

So wrote this code in python and it works. It does what I need. But i was wondering if there is any over way to create the name of each df in a different way rather than using

```
globals()\["df\_"+str(ciudad)\] = new_grouped_by
```

If I try this:

```
"df\_"+str(ciudad) = new_grouped_by
```

Give me this error: `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`

Any tips/suggestions would be more than welcome!

```
def get_city():
    for ciudad in df["Ciudad"].unique():
        #print (ciudad)
        grouped_by = df.groupby('Ciudad')
        new_grouped_by=[grouped_by.get_group(ciudad) for i in grouped_by.groups]
        globals()["df_"+str(ciudad)] = new_grouped_by

get_city()
```

Comment: why are you trying to do this?

Comment: It is a part of my class practice. So I have differente df for ech city. If the city is called Madrid, then the df generated would be df_Madrid. Then I can access it easily.
So i was wondering if there is any other way to give the names to those df.
(Sorry, I am learning python since last month, so I am still no use to write in a technical way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to store the dataframes in a dictionary with the city names as keys:

```
import pandas as pd

data = zip(['Amsterdam', 'Amsterdam', 'Barcelona'],[1,22,333])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Ciudad', 'data'])
new_dfs = dict(list(df.groupby('Ciudad')))
```

Calling `new_dfs['Amsterdam']` will then give you the dataframe:

|  | Ciudad | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Amsterdam | 1 |
| 1 | Amsterdam | 22 |

Comment: OHHHH! I did not think about doing that!! Thank you so much